# ASP.NET GridView Sorting Implementation & Event Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

Can someone share how to practically implement gridview sorting and handle that event if:

> 1. The data is binded manually
> 2. Gridview is built using template field that is pumped from code behind only (not from the markups)

I build my gridview solely from codebehind therefore I can't use the default method or solution.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want sample code for inbuilt feature of sorting of gridview?

Comment: have you googled this. http://weblogs.asp.net/vikram/archive/2008/04/15/manually-sorting-and-paging-gridview-without-using-datasource-control.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608049/sorting-gridview-in-asp-net-c

Comment: for ur second point u can refer this link     http://forums.asp.net/t/1001702.aspx

Comment: My friend the link you provide indeed satisfy my 1st requirement but it doens't satisfy my 2nd requirement (yes I have tested it). And yes I have googled it. tQ

Comment: @Alok I don't expect exact answer.. Just share anything that comes into your mind when you read the question..

Comment: @ reshma, I am doing sth like the one in your link already.. that link basically doesn't provide any help..

Comment: Try this http://weblogs.asp.net/vikram/archive/2008/04/15/manually-sorting-and-paging-gridview-without-using-datasource-control.aspx

Comment: I use this already my friend it's not helping.. this only works if you autogenerate the columns, where in my case i build the columns one by one..

Comment: Other approach could be just do the sorting manually. Suppose you have a SP which returns data from database which you are displaying in your asp.Net page. Alter SP pass two more parameters SortType (may be column names) and SortOrder('Asc' or 'desc') and retrieve it on the basis of parameter passed. In short do the sorting on data itself instead on gridview.

Comment: My biggest problems is: since I generate the columns using codebehind.. he columns header is not clickable! the normal gridview allow sorting thru allowing clicking in the header. whereas mine can't! the sorting handling is not basically a big deal.. if possible i would like to allow this header clickable 1st

Comment: add link in your header while creating it. Use RowDataBoud event and use if(e.rowtype = GridviewRowType.HeaderRow) then find your link and add "onClick" attribute to it.
Let me know if you want exact code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    listBindByName(); //this would be your procedure to look for the data you want
    DataSet dsSortTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataSet;
    DataTable dtSortTable = dsSortTable.Tables[0];
    if (dtSortTable != null)
    {
        DataView dvSortedView = new DataView(dtSortTable);
        dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + getSortDirectionString();
        ViewState["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
        GridView1.DataSource = dvSortedView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}

private string getSortDirectionString()
{
    if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
    {
        ViewState["sortDirection"] = "ASC";
    }
    else
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString() == "ASC")
        {
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = "DESC";
            return ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString();
        }
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString() == "DESC")
        {
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = "ASC";
            return ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString();
}
```

This is an example of the TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Visible="true" runat="server" ID="descriptionLabel" Text='<%# bind("description")  %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDescription" Width="100px" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("description") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

By adding the SortExpression property the GridView header will become clickable. Make sure the sort expression attribute is the name of the field that you are binding through the sql query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I achieve something like that with my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148278/why-do-i-get-a-column-not-found-error-while-sorting-a-gridview

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Best to use the shortened routine below - which can be further shortened */        
private string GetSortDirectionString()
{
    if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null) ViewState["sortDirection"] = "ASC";

    var currDir = ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString().ToUpper();

    switch (currDir)
    {
        case "ASC": ViewState["sortDirection"] = "DESC"; break;
        case "DESC": ViewState["sortDirection"] = "ASC"; break; 
    }

    return ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Grid view Sorting In asp .net**

**Step ONE**
Add grid view to your page edit the source code by adding **allow sorting** true and initiating an event by **on sorting**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"  runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Step Two**

In the code behind page..we need to handle this event **"GridView1_Sorting"** and the data table binding.
On page load we will bind the datatable with the gridview

```
 dt = Class1.getDataSet().Tables[0]; // here dt is the datatable object declared Globally.
 GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

so now if we run our code the grid view will be visible but no sorting.

**Step Three**

Next we need to handle the Gridview Sorting Event.
First of all we need to declare one static string SortDirection.

```
 protected void SetSortDirection(string sortDirection)
        {
            if (sortDirection == "ASC")
            {
                _sortDirection = "DESC";
            }
            else
            {
                _sortDirection = "ASC";
            }
        }
```

so the sortDirection is a static string...This function we used to switch between ascendin and descending...
**Step 4**

```
 protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        SetSortDirection(SortDirection);
        if (dt != null)
        {
            //Sort the data.
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + _sortDirection;
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            SortDireaction = _sortDirection;
        }
    }
```

so we have completed our sorting.... **sortExpression** is nothing but the column name...