# Why do I get a column not found error while sorting a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

```
<asp:GridView AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#E2E2E2" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="There is no data to display" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Details" SortExpression="TaskDetails" ItemStyle-Width="35%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Services" HeaderText="Services" SortExpression="ServiceName" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="TheStatus" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due Date" SortExpression="DueDate" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PullData();
    }
}

public void PullData()
{
    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    string connString = @"user id = user;" + "password= pss$$$$; server= dev-magician; database= OnBase;" /*+ "Trusted_Connection=yes;"*/  + "connection timeout=30";
    string query = @"SELECT  'http://mg/appnet/workview/objectPop.aspx?objectid=' + CAST(CT.OBJECTID AS VARCHAR) + '&classid=1224' 'Task Detail'
            ,UG.USERGROUPNAME 'Services'
            ,CT.ATTR2812 'Status'
            ,CT.ATTR2752 'Due Date'
            ,CT.ATTR2739 'Task Name'

        FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT LEFT JOIN HSI.USERGROUP UG on CT.FK2743 = UG.USERGROUPNUM
        WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
            da.Fill(taskData);
            //conn.Close();
            yourTasksGV.DataSource = taskData;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            Session["sortData"] = taskData;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}

protected void yourTasksGV_Sorting(object server, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    /*string strSortExpression = e.SortExpression;
    switch (strSortExpression)
    {
        case "TaskDetails":
            MessageBox.Show("Task Details");
            break;
    }*/
    DataTable dataTable = Session["sortData"] as DataTable;

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirection(e.SortDirection);

        yourTasksGV.DataSource = dataView;
        yourTasksGV.DataBind();
    }
}
private string ConvertSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
    string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

    switch (sortDirection)
    {
        case SortDirection.Ascending:
            newSortDirection = "ASC";
            break;

        case SortDirection.Descending:
            newSortDirection = "DESC";
            break;
    }

    return newSortDirection;
}
```

What I am looking to achieve is whenever I click on any of the header it should sort the GridView but no matter which header text I click on to sort, I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column ServiceName.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column ServiceName.]
   System.Data.DataTable.ParseSortString(String sortString) +5313286
   System.Data.DataView.CheckSort(String sort) +35
   System.Data.DataView.set_Sort(String value) +115
   TestOnBase.Pages.Default.yourTasksGV_Sorting(Object server, GridViewSortEventArgs e) +256
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnSorting(GridViewSortEventArgs e) +122
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleSort(String sortExpression, SortDirection sortDirection) +65
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleSort(String sortExpression) +78
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +497
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +205
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9528578
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I modify the code so that whichever header text the user clicks it, it sorts and then on another click it sorts the opposite and so forth?

DataTable:

[image]

How it is displayed to the user:

[image]

Comment: first thing, the sortexpression values should be equal to the names of the columns of your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting on the expression `ServiceName` but your column is named `Services`.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Services"
    HeaderText="Services"
    SortExpression="Services"
    ItemStyle-Width="25%"
    ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
```

For more clarification, the `SortExpression` is used to sort the data source you are binding to your control. So, like a SQL `ORDER BY` statement, you specify the column you want to sort it by.

So in your query, you are returning five columns: Task Detail, Services, Status, Due Date, and Task Name. When you bind the 'Services' column to a label, that is also the column that must be sorted, because the underlying data source has a 'Services' column. So even if your GridView's column header is something completely different, you still need to sort it by the *column name of the data source.*

Comment: What about the HyperLinkField? It doesnt have a DataField?

Comment: It has a `DataTextField` though. Your `SortExpression` should be whatever column from your query you are binding it to.

Comment: So change everything to be same? I am taking the Text from `Task Name` and displaying it in the `Task Detail` cell... So pretty much the link is the `Task Detail` value and the link text display is the `Task Name` value.

Comment: I changed Services and Status to match DataField and SortExpression but when I click on them, the page just reloads :/

Comment: See my edit for further explanation. When you put a breakpoint in your `yourTasksGV_Sorting` handler, right after you sort your DataView, is the data sorted correctly?

Comment: Thank you. So `SortExpression` is the same as the Column name in the SQL Query and `DataField` is then what?

Comment: I think I have made the changes but whenever I click on the header, the page just refreshes :/

Comment: When I click on the Task Detail header, I would like to sort by Task Name because that is what I am displaying to the user. I updated my question with the DataTable which is shown during the execution.

Comment: `DataField` would also be the column name from the query you want to display.

Comment: I added an UpdatePanel so it only refreshes without reloading the page but not when I click on the header, nothing happens

Comment: This http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-2-0-Gridview-Sorting-Using-C-sharp.aspx seems to work for me :) I was looking to add an image and updated my question but it's not working